# python concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExcutor tasks per child

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there a way to limit the tasks per child in ProcessPoolExecutor from
concurrent.futures module?

(like in multiprocessing.Pool)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool

(see maxtasksperchild arg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. There is no mechanism that keep track of the number of tasks performed by a worker in the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. Thus you cannot do it without modifying the internal code of python.

A solution could be to implement this feature in [loky](https://github.com/tomMoral/loky). This is a library to improve `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and fix some of its bugs. It provides a mechanism for worker timeout and it would be easy to implement a task counter that "timeout" when `maxtasks` is reached. If you need this feature, I suggest putting an issue on the loky repo.

Answer (score 0):

[Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) supports that.

```
from pebble import ProcessPool

def function(foo, bar=0):
    return foo + bar

with ProcessPool(max_workers=5, max_tasks=10) as pool:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        future = pool.schedule(function, args=[i])
        future.result()
```

Comment: Does Pebble build upon `multiprocessing` or upon `concurrent.futures`? The limitation of `multiprocessing.Pool` is that it doesn't support a nested pool. Does Pebble support a nested pool?